# Can't Find a Good Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I am looking to ask a question regarding which areas of chemistry use group theory from mathematics and whether there are particular areas that might be attainable for an undergraduate looking to complete a senior thesis.  I am a math professor with no knowledge of chemistry.  The problem is that I don't know an appropriate tag, since "math" and "group theory" don't exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you tag it [symmetry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symmetry), and let us retag it [group-theory](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory) ([math](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) sounds a bit vague to me).